# pythoncom.PumpMessages() gives warning "no reference PumpMessages() in pythoncom"

Tags: python, keylogger, pythoncom

I am making a keylogger, but every source I see needs that function and it is not working properly.

I tried to update the library and it didn't fix the problem.
all the code is working except the part below.
I have no idea what the below means. pls, help me understand.
if you know a similar function pls help.
I am 14 years old so, I am not experienced will enough.
2 years in C Language. and 1-year web programming. and 1-year python pro.

```
obj = pyHook.HookManager()
obj.KeyDown = keypressed
obj.HookKeyboard()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

Comment: Please post the *exact* message including the stack trace, if any.

Comment: Hi @BoarGules , the message it gives is litterarly: cannot find reference 'PumpMessages' in 'pythoncom.py'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a Python error message. Unless I am mistaken, you are running PyCharm and you are getting a PyCharm popup when you mouse over the highlighted attribute `PumpMessages`.

This is nothing to worry about. It is happening because PyCharm's analysis doesn't always know how to examine Python extensions in DLLs. As PyCharm itself says,

> This inspection detects names that should resolve but don't. Due to dynamic dispatch and duck typing, this is possible in a limited but useful number of cases.

One of the limitations of this inspection is functions in DLLs, which are dynamically dispatched.

If you look in the file `pythoncom.py` you will see that it doesn't in fact contain a definition of the function `PumpMessages`, only two lines that import `pythoncom3x.dll`. The function definition lives in that DLL and PyCharm can't find it there, because it would have to execute the code to establish where to look. The message is a false alarm.

If it bothers you, put the caret on the highlight, hit alt-Enter, click the lightbulb icon, and select one of the options to disable reporting of unresolved references, either for the function or for the entire `pythoncom` module. Otherwise just ignore it.

To turn it back on, hit ctrl-alt-S (Settings), choose Editor | Inspections | Python | Unresolved references.

So if your program isn't working as expected, look for the cause elsewhere. This warning is not the problem.